# How to add custom validation in my form in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to add few custom rules to my create student form. I want to create student in 3 steps one after another. If a user completes the info in first step then only should allow to continue to 2nd and so on to 3rd and create at the end. 
I want to achieve this functionality through custom validation using StoreStudentRequest.php file.

I have not really tried anything because i am new to laravel right now so i need help building up the logic for this functionality

StudentController.php

```
public function store(StoreStudentRequest $request)
    {
        $this->studentRepository->create(
            [
                'bus_id' => $request['bus_id'],
                'room_id' => $request['room_id'],
                'grade_id' => $request['grade_id'],
                'teacher_id' => $request['teacher_id'],
                'passport_no' => $request['passport_no'],
                'passport_expiry' => $request['passport_expiry'],
                //similar fields continues
            ]);

        return redirect()->route('admin.auth.student.index')->withFlashSuccess(__('alerts.backend.students.created'));
    }
```

StoreStudentRequest.php

```
class StoreStudentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            'name' => ['required'],
            'dob' => ['required'],
            'gender' => ['required'],
            'religion' => ['required'],
            'ethnicity' => ['required'],
            'nationality' => ['required'],
            'guardian_residency_type' => ['required'],
            'applicant_qid_no' => ['required'],
            'qid_validity' => ['required'],
          //similar fields continue
        ];
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
                <div role="tabpanel">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#step-one" class="nav-link active" aria-controls="step-one" role="tab"
                               data-toggle="tab">@lang('navs.frontend.user.step-one')</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#step-two" class="nav-link" aria-controls="step-two" role="tab"
                               data-toggle="tab">@lang('navs.frontend.user.step-two')</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#step-three" class="nav-link" aria-controls="step-three" role="tab"
                               data-toggle="tab">@lang('navs.frontend.user.step-three')</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--tab panel-->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active pt-3" id="step-one"
                         aria-labelledby="step-one-tab">
                        @include('backend.auth.student.show.tabs.step-one')
                    </div><!--tab panel profile-->

                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show pt-3" id="step-two" aria-labelledby="step-two-tab">
                        @include('backend.auth.student.show.tabs.step-two')
                    </div><!--tab panel profile-->

                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show pt-3" id="step-three"
                         aria-labelledby="step-three-tab">
                        @include('backend.auth.student.show.tabs.step-three')
                    </div><!--tab panel change password-->
                </div><!--tab content-->
            </div><!--card body-->
```

As you can see in create.blade.php i have converted the form into 3 steps. Now I want that in first step user should be able to input lets say from name to "name" to "religion" fields and then if user has filled these fields only then move to the next step of filling other fields and so on. Also i want to add a functionality to give option to user to save each step in database if user decides to complete the form later.

Please help if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StoreStudentRequest.php

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        if (request('stage') == 'stage-1') {
            $rules = $this->stage1Rule();
        } else if (request('stage') == 'stage-2') {
            $rules = $this->stage2Rule();
        } else if (request('stage') == 'stage-3') {
            $rules = $this->stage3Rule();
        }
        return $rules;
    }

    private function stage1Rule()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required'],
            'dob' => ['required'],
            'gender' => ['required'],
            'religion' => ['required'],
        ];
    }

    private
    function stage2Rule()
    {
        return [
            'ethnicity' => ['required'],
            'nationality' => ['required'],
            'guardian_residency_type' => ['required'],
        ];
    }

    private function stage3Rule()
    {
        return [
            'passport_no' => $request['passport_no'],
            'passport_expiry' => $request['passport_expiry'],
        ];
    }
```

**This is how I figured out to lay down the rules and it is working just fine for me according to my requirements. However I would like to thank everyone who contributed to this. Stay Blessed!

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom validation in StoreStudentRequest.php.

Let part 1 => name to religion /

Let part 2 => ethnicity to guardian_residency_type

I think that can let user to input 1st part and if user start to fill ethnicity, the other fields will become required.

```php
class StoreStudentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            'name' => ['required'],
            'dob' => ['required'],
            'gender' => ['required'],
            'religion' => ['required'],

          //similar fields continue
        ];
    }
    public function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $v = parent::getValidatorInstance();
    $v->sometimes(['ethnicity','nationality','guardian_residency_type'],'required', function($input) {
        return ($input->ethnicity <> null or $input->ethnicity <> null or $input->ethnicity <> null) and $input->name <> null and $input->dob <> null and $input->gender <> null and $input->religion <> null;
    });

    $v->sometimes(['applicant_qid_no','qid_validity'],'required', function($input) {
        return ($input->applicant_qid_no <> null or $input->qid_validity <> null) and $input->ethnicity <> null and $input->nationality <> null and $input->guardian_residency_type <> null;
    });

    return $v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where to use getValidatorInstance()?

Comment: return ($input->ethnicity <> null or $input->ethnicity <> null or $input->ethnicity <> null)
can you kindly explain this to me? Why have you used same check on ethnicity thrice?

Comment: im facing some confusion in understanding the third part that would be from 'applicant_qid_no' => ['required'], to 'qid_validity' => ['required'], can you kindly help me creating that one as well? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Fahad I updated my answer. Let me know, if you have any confusion.

Comment: thnx for all the help. Although i tried your code but didnt work out for my requirements. I posted an answer which i figured out with some help and is working for me, you can check it out below if you want. Thanks :)